# Отправить почту, чтобы "От кого" стоял произвольный email

Tags: c#, email

Есть обратная связь, пользователь должен заполнить обязательное поле Email.
При нажатии на кнопку отправить, письмо отправляется на support@домен.ком.

Задача:Чтобы в пришедшем письме в поле "от кого" стояла почта клиента (Email), а не sender@домен.ком.

Цель: Далее, чтобы пользователь в почтовике нажал кнопку "ответить" и начал переписку с клиентом.

Подскажите, как реализовать на C# и есть ли такая возможность.

```
    public class _MailSender
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Вложения, по умолчанию null
    /// </summary>
    public List<Attachment> Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Содержимое письма, по умолчанию пустое
    /// </summary>
    public string Body = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Отправитель, по умолчанию значение берется из конфига
    /// </summary>
    public string EmailFrom = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Mailsender_email_from"];

    /// <summary>
    /// Адресат(ы), указываются через ',' или ';', по умолчанию значение пустое
    /// </summary>
    public string EmailTo = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Является ли содержимое письма HTML, по умолчанию true
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsBodyHtml = true;

    /// <summary>
    /// Использовать ли защищенный протокол SSL, по умолчанию false
    /// </summary>
    public bool SMTPEnableSsl = _Data.GetBool(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Mailsender_smtp_use_ssl"]);

    /// <summary>
    /// SMTP Логин, по умолчанию значение берется из конфига. Если не указан логин или пароль 
    /// SmtpServer.Credentials установлен не будет
    /// </summary>
    public string SMTPLogin = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Mailsender_smtp_login"];

    /// <summary>
    /// SMTP Пароль, по умолчанию значение берется из конфига. Если не указан логин или пароль 
    /// SmtpServer.Credentials установлен не будет
    /// </summary>
    public string SMTPPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Mailsender_smtp_password"];

    /// <summary>
    /// SMTP Порт, по умолчанию 25
    /// </summary>
    public int SMTPPort = _Data.GetInt(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Mailsender_smtp_port"]);

    /// <summary>
    /// SMTP Сервер, по умолчанию значение берется из конфига
    /// </summary>
    public string SMTPServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Mailsender_smtp_server"];

    /// <summary>
    /// Тема письма
    /// </summary>
    public string Subject = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Ссылка для отписки
    /// </summary>
    public string ListUnsubscribe = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Делегат для ассинхронной отправки писем
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mailMessage"></param>
    private delegate void SomeDelegate(MailMessage mailMessage);

    /// <summary>
    /// Отправляет сообщение с настройками заданными в этом классе
    /// </summary>



    public void MailSend()
    {
        // Обработка ошибок входящих параметров
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SMTPServer)) throw new Exception("Нет настроек почты. Сообщение не отправлено");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.EmailTo)) throw new Exception("Не указаны получатели. Сообщение не отправлено");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.EmailFrom)) throw new Exception("Не указан электронный адрес отправителя. Сообщение не отправлено");

        // Меняем разделитель, на тот, который поддерживает MailMessage
        EmailTo = EmailTo.Replace(";", ",");

        MailMessage mailMessage = null;
        // Формирование сообщения
        try
        {
            mailMessage = new MailMessage(new MailAddress(this.EmailFrom), new MailAddress(this.EmailTo));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception(ex.Message); }

        // Отправитель и получатель (проверка на валидность адресов)
        try { mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(this.EmailFrom); }
        catch (FormatException) { throw new Exception("Электронный адрес отправителя не соответствует формату. Сообщение не отправлено"); }
        try { mailMessage.To.Add(this.EmailTo); }
        catch (FormatException) { throw new Exception("Электронный адрес получателя(ей) не соответствует формату. Сообщение не отправлено"); }

        if (_Data.GetString(ListUnsubscribe) != "")
        {
            mailMessage.Headers.Add("List-Unsubscribe", ListUnsubscribe);
        }

        mailMessage.Subject = this.Subject;
        mailMessage.Body = this.Body;
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = this.IsBodyHtml;

        foreach (Attachment a in this.Attachments)
            mailMessage.Attachments.Add(a);

        // Формирование смтпКлиента
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(this.SMTPServer);
        client.Port = this.SMTPPort;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SMTPLogin)
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SMTPPassword))
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(this.SMTPLogin, this.SMTPPassword);
        client.EnableSsl = this.SMTPEnableSsl;
        //client.Send(mailMessage);
        try
        {
            client.Send(mailMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Признаюсь, поторопился с вопросом... просто не знал, на сколько реально это сделать. Выше код работает, может кому понадобиться. Спасибо. В EmailFrom - можно указать любой email.

Comment: @Oxot_nik, для ответа есть заголовок `Reply-To:`, а если вы во `From:` будете добавлять email отличный от почтового аккаунта с которого письмо уходит, такое письмо 100% попадет в спам.

Comment: @Visman, согласен с Вами.  Добавил `mailMessage.ReplyToList.Add("email@example.com");`